# How to create quintile of variable in R

Tags: r, stat

Is it possible to bin a variable in to quintile (1/5th) using R. And select only the variables that fall in the 5th bin.

- As of now I am using the closest option which is quartile (.75) as there is not a function to do quintile.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: `Hmisc::cut2()` with `g = 5` should to the trick.

Comment: Not a function to do quantiles ? Sure about that ?

Comment: Thanks m-dz that is right to the point....

Answer (score 4):

Not completely sure what you mean, but this divides a dataset into 5 equal groups based on value and subsequently selects the fifth group

```
obs = rnorm(100)
qq = quantile(obs, probs = seq(0, 1, .2))
obs[obs >= qq[5]]
```